# Get Values From Html To jquery using onkeyup function with element id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As i'm trying to get the values from html to jquery using onkeyup function for getting key pressed data by ID i tried but i could not able to get the value in alert i don't know whats wrong in my code. Can Anyone Help Me.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').keypress(function() {
      var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
      alert("value",value);
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Comment: @UllasHunka I'm guessing the code that's clearly visible in the question...?

Comment: @UllasHunka I understood the question. I gues Rory did too, because he answered it. So what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

`alert("value", value);` Comma and Add `alert("value : " + value);`

```js
$('#test').keypress(function() {
  var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
  alert("value :"+ value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="test" type="text">
```

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is correct. The issue is because you're providing two arguments to `alert()` when it only accepts a single one.

Aside from that you should use `console.log` for debugging, and you can access the element which triggered the event by using the `this` keyword in the event handler. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').keypress(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log("value", value);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Also note that `keyup` or `input` may be a more appropriate event to use, as `keypress` fires before the new key is added to the value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(
      function() {
          $('#test').keypress(

          function() {
            var values = document.getElementById('test').value;
            alert("value"+values);
          });
      })</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="test" type="text" value="2">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keyup` and modify alert as given below:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('#test').keyup(

        function() {
          var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
          alert(value);
        });
    })

</script>


<input id="test" type="text">
```

In your code, the event is fired on keypress, hence it takes the old value. So, in case of empty input field, it will alert the empty value but in case of keyup, it will alert the value which is already filled by the user.

Demo with keyup: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/4020/

Demo with keypress: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/4023/

Answer (score 0):

Dont mix javascript  with jquery, you only need $(this).val() to get the value, use keyup ()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').keyup(function() {
      var _value = $(this).val();
      alert("value " + _value);
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="text">
```